# Building processing screen for customer locations

Tags: acumatica

I need to build a processing screen for customer locations that determines and then updates the residential flag on locations.

This code correctly processes each selected record and appears to update the appropriate fields. But the problem I am encountering is that my changes to `Location` are not being saved back to the database.

The Customer Locations graph requires the business account to be specified before you can enter a Location ID, and I suspect that because of that I cannot simply update the Locations view on the graph. But I cannot find any documentation or code examples indicating what approach I should use here.

Here is the code on my processing screen graph:

```
public class ProcessCustomerLocations : PXGraph<ProcessCustomerLocations>
{
    public PXCancel<Location> Cancel;
    public PXProcessing<Location, Where<Location.isActive, Equal<True>>> Locations;

    public static void Process(List<Location> locations)
    {
        var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<CustomerLocationMaint>();
        CustomerLocationMaint_Extension graphExt = graph.GetExtension<CustomerLocationMaint_Extension>();

        foreach (var location in locations)
        {
            graphExt.UpdateLocation(location, true);
        }
    }

    public ProcessCustomerLocations()
    {
        Locations.SetProcessDelegate(Process);
    }

}
```

And here is my code on the CustomerLocationMaint_Extension graph:

```
public class CustomerLocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CustomerLocationMaint>
{
  public void UpdateLocation(Location location, bool isMassProcess = false)
    {
        bool isRes = false;

        Base.Location.Current = Base.Location.Search<Location.locationID>(location.LocationID, location.BAccountID);
        LocationExt locationExt = location.GetExtension<LocationExt>();

        // INSERT CODE TO DETERMINE VALUE OF isRes
        locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated = true;
        location.CResedential = isRes;

        Base.Location.Update(location);
        Base.Actions.PressSave();
    }
}
```

One of the fields I am updating on Location is a custom field called `UsrResidentialValidated`. Here is the code for that field.

```
namespace PX.Objects.CR
{
  public class LocationExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Location>
  {          
    #region UsrResidentialValidated
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Residential Validated")]

    public virtual bool? UsrResidentialValidated { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrResidentialValidated : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to some help from @Samvel I've modified the `UpdateLocation` code as follows. The following code does save the changes to the database (both on the custom field and the non-custom field), which is great. However, in order to do that, I had to create a new Location object "myLocation" and am no longer using the "location" object that the PXProcessing graph passed to UpdateLocation. This means that after processing, when the processing screen displays the processed records with the modified data (after processing finishes and before you refresh the screen), it does not show the updated values. Is there any way to both have the processing screen show the updated values and save the changes to the database?

```
    public void UpdateLocation(PX.Objects.CR.Location location, bool isMassProcess = false)
    {
        bool isRes = true;

        Location myLocation = PXSelect<Location,
              Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>, And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Location.locationID>>>>>
              .Select(this.Base, location.BAccountID, location.LocationID);

        this.Base.Location.Current = myLocation;

        LocationExt locationExt = myLocation.GetExtension<LocationExt>();
        locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated = true;

        myLocation.CResedential = isRes;
        Base.Location.Current = Base.Location.Update(myLocation);

        this.Base.Save.Press();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

I have updated the code to correspond to your case. After processing all the records the records in the grid are being updated and showing modified records.
You can download the customization package for this code by [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kgwPDcLPJjQrrVuw-OKc6949cLioGzFv)

To create a processing page for updating Location you should do the following steps:

1. Add "Selected" field to the Location DAC

   ```
   public sealed class LocationExt: PXCacheExtension<Location>
   {
       #region Selected
       public abstract class selected : IBqlField
       { }
       [PXBool()]
       [PXDefault(true,PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
       public bool? Selected { get; set; }
       #endregion
       #region UsrResidentialValidated
       [PXDBBool]
       [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Residential Validated")]
       public bool? UsrResidentialValidated { get; set; }
       public abstract class usrResidentialValidated : IBqlField { }
       #endregion
   }
   ```

   This step is required because otherwise your delegate for `SetProcessDelegate` will never be called. 
   ***Acumatica is checking if there is at least one selected record before calling Process Delegate.***
2. Create the Processing Graph like below:

   ```
   using PX.Data;
   using PX.Objects.CR;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   namespace CustomerLocationUpdate
   {
       public class ProcessCustomerLocations : PXGraph<ProcessCustomerLocations>
       {
           public PXCancel<Location> Cancel;
           public PXProcessingJoin<Location,InnerJoin<BAccountR,On<Location.bAccountID,Equal<BAccountR.bAccountID>>>, 
       Where<Location.isActive, Equal<True>,And<Location.locType, Equal<PX.Objects.CR.LocTypeList.customerLoc>>>> Locations;

           public static void Process(List<Location> locations)
           {
               var graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.Objects.AR.CustomerLocationMaint>();
               CustomerLocationMaint_Extension graphExt = graph.GetExtension<CustomerLocationMaint_Extension>();

               foreach (var location in locations)
               {
                   graphExt.UpdateLocation(location, true);
                   graph.Clear();
               }
           }

           public ProcessCustomerLocations()
           {
               Locations.SetProcessDelegate(Process);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see I have implicitly specified PX.Objects.AR and PX.Objects.CR for some reason the program has worked only this way on my instance.
3. Create the UpdateLocation method in the GraphExtension:

   ```
   using PX.Data;

   namespace CustomerLocationUpdate
   {
       public class CustomerLocationMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AR.CustomerLocationMaint>
       {
           public void UpdateLocation(PX.Objects.CR.Location location, bool isMassProcess = false)
           {
               bool isRes = false;
               this.Base.Location.Current = PXSelect<PX.Objects.CR.Location,Where<PX.Objects.CR.Location.bAccountID,Equal<Required<PX.Objects.CR.Location.bAccountID>>,And<PX.Objects.CR.Location.locationID,Equal<Required<PX.Objects.CR.Location.locationID>>>>>.Select(this.Base,location.BAccountID,location.LocationID);
               this.Base.Location.Current.CResedential = isRes;
               LocationExt locationExt = PXCache<PX.Objects.CR.Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(this.Base.Location.Current);
               locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated = false;
               this.Base.Location.Current = this.Base.Location.Update(this.Base.Location.Current);
               this.Base.Save.Press();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see I am setting the `Location.Current` using PXSelect and not `Location.Current.Search`.
   For some reason `Location.Current.Search` is always returning null. 
   May be it is caused by the PXProjectionAttribute applied to it, I am not sure what is the exact reason.

Comment: this is only partially working for me. You'll notice there are two fields I want to update: `location.CResedential` and `locationExt.UsrResidentialValidated` One is a custom field and one is not. With this approach, only the change to CResidenial (the non-custom field) is being saved to the database, and the change to the Usr field is not. Also, after processing, the processing screen displays the processed records with the updated data. This initial result indicates that the Usr field was updated while the CResedential field was not, which is the opposite of what is persisted

Comment: @abulger did you add the update of your custom field to my code example? I have not written exact code to work as it is provided this is an initial example of how you can update data on Location's record.

Comment: yes I updated my code to include the changes you provided. Your changes allow me successfully change the non-custom fields, but still the changes to my custom field are not being persisted.

Comment: @abulger can you please add the definition of your custom field to the question?

Comment: yes, I can do that! I've added the custom field code to the original question. I also added an updated version of `UpdateLocation` which is based on your suggestion but which creates a new Location object. This version successfully saves changes to both the custom field and the non-custom field. So that's progress! However, because we're no longer dealing with "location" as passed in from the processing graph, the data displayed in the processing result (once processing finishes but before you refresh the screen) is not updated. Any ideas?

Comment: @abulger I will try to review this in the evening and let you know how to achieve that.

Comment: thanks for your help on this. I downloaded and published the customization file you provided, but I am still running into the issue where the results displayed after processing are not showing the updated values. For example, if I select a record which has `CResedential` set to True, processing should change that value to False. Instead, when I process that record, the screen displays that record with a green check but the value of `CResedential` is still displaying True, even though the value in the database was actually changed to False.

Comment: If in in the `UpdateLocation` function I modify the `location` parameter directly (as in my original code), then the processing results are updated correctly but the database value is not changed. If I instead modify `this.Base.Location.Current` (as if your code) then the values are saved to the database but not displayed on the results screen. One workaround would be to modify both `location` and `this.Base.Location.Current`, but that seems less than ideal.

Comment: @abulger which version of Acumatica are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2018 R2, build 18.211.0032